how to set static IP on newer debian
I'm trying to set a static IP on a new raspbian lite OS.
I used to be able to set a static IP address on older debian systems by modifying the /etc/network/interfaces file, but this OS doesn't have such a file. when I add the file with the following:
auto eth0
iface eth0 static
    address 192.168.1.15/24
    gateway 192.168.1.1

the iface gets deconfigured. it doesn't even take the dhcp value. what am I missing / doing wrong?

Try doing config in /etc/dhcpcd.conf (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39785)

On a Debian 12.6 machine I built I was seeing similar issues; it turned out to be connman failing and setting the IP to a link-local one (169.254.x.x).  I solved it by disabling connman; systemctl disable connman and rebooting.  Dunni if connman is part of you Pi install, but worth checking!

From https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#networking :

Note: Starting with Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm, Network Manager is the default networking configuration tool. Earlier versions of Raspberry Pi OS used dhcpd and other tools for network configuration.

With NetworkManager, there is a connection name that is separate from network device name, and is intended for human consumption only; the default name depends on which NetworkManager frontend created the default connection, but might be something like Wired connection 1. It might even be the same as the network device name the connection is meant to apply to, e.g. eth0.
Having a connection definition separate from network device names enables things like defining the connection parameters for a particular WiFi network just once, and then being able to use that definition with any WiFi adapter that is connected to the system, or will be in the future. But for simple wired network configurations, it is one extra step.
When you have more than one active network device, I prefer using the connection name as a brief human-readable description of the connection's purpose, like Production or Backup for example. But when there is just one wired network device on the system, and no reason to have multiple possible configurations for it, I personally prefer using the name of the network device as the connection name.
So, first run nmcli connection show to view the current connection definitions and the network devices they're applied to. To view the contents of a particular connection definition, run e.g. nmcli connection show "Wired connection 1".
If there is an existing connection definition, you could use nmcli connection modify to change it.
All nmcli sub-commands can be shortened to the shortest non-ambiguous form to save typing: I tend to shorten nmcli connection show to nmcli c show and nmcli connection modify to nmcli c mod etc.
For example, if there is a pre-existing Wired connection 1 definition:
nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1" connection.id eth0   #rename connection to "eth0" for typing convenience
nmcli c mod eth0 connection.interface-name eth0  #ensure connection is associated with a particular interface
nmcli c mod eth0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli c mod eth0 ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.15/24
nmcli c mod eth0 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
nmcli c mod eth0 connection.autoconnect yes   #to make it auto-start at boot

Then to activate the connection with the new settings immediately:
nmcli c up eth0

For more details, see this page for generic connection settings (connection.*), this page for IPv4-specific settings (ipv4.*), or this page for all NetworkManager settings categories.
If there is no existing connection, you'll have to create it first:
nmcli c add \
    connection.type ethernet \
    connection.id Production \
    connection.interface-name eth0 \
    ipv4.method manual \
    ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.15/24 \
    ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1 \
    connection.autoconnect yes

Then activate it as before:
nmcli c up Production

Alternatively, you might want to check if nmtui is installed: it is a friendly menu-based NetworkManager front-end that works on text-only displays.

thank you very much for your comprehensive response. I will test this out as soon as I get back home tomorrow, and let you know how it goes.

@NicolasStraub - you can also use nmtui if you prefer
